# How to extract fields from JSON string in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

In Splunk after searching I am getting below result-

`FINISH  OnDemandModel - Model: Application:GVAP RequestID:test_manifest_0003 Project:AMPS EMRid:j-XHFRN0A4M3QQ status:success`

I want to extract fields like Application, RequestID, Project, EMRid and status as columns and corresponding values as those columns' values.

I am new to Splunk and not sure how to use spath or other search commands.

Comment: To learn how to use some Splunk search commands, take the free Splunk Fundamentals 1 course at https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html

Comment: @RichG - Fundamentals I is good ... but (at least when I took it years ago), it didn't get much into field extraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `rex` [command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex):

```
<search>
rex field=yourfield "Application:(?<application>\w+)\sRequestID:(?<requestid>\w+)\sProject:(?<project>\w+)\sEMRid:(?<emrid>\w+)\sstatus:(?<status>\w+)"
```

Fine-tune your regexes over at regex101.com